# post increment operator running a for loop into infinite loop

Tags: loops, post-increment

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<10; )
{
   i=i++;
   printf("Hello\n");
}
```

the following code is running into infinite loop. Can any one help me understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Its an infinite loop due to the line i = i++ which works as follows. (Suppose i = 1)
1) 'i' is increased by 1. (So i = 2)
2) The value of i++ i.e. value before increment is assigned to 'i'. (So i = 1)

So, the value of 'i' won't change, condition 'i < 10' will never be false thereby leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: But as it is post increment operator first 'i' should get assigned to 1. Then 'i' should get incremented to 2. isn't it?

Comment: @ Viswa Sairaman : Increment operator has more _precedence_ than Assignment operator. So if 'i' is 1, increment is done first, which means 'i' becomes 2 and 'i++' returns 1, which is assigned to 'i', making it 1.